# Evaluation of definite Integral Containing Rational functions..

Tags: integration

> Evaluation of $$\int_{-5}^{-2}\left(\frac{x^2-x}{x^3-3x+1}\right)^2dx+\int_{\frac{1}{6}}^{\frac{1}{3}}\left(\frac{x^2-x}{x^3-3x+1}\right)^2dx+\int_{\frac{6}{5}}^{\frac{3}{2}}\left(\frac{x^2-x}{x^3-3x+1}\right)^2dx$$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Here Denominator of all rational function is not defined when $x^3-3x+1=0$

So Using Derivative test::

$\displaystyle f(x)=x^3-3x+1\;,$ Then $f'(x)=3x^2-3$ and $f''(x)=6x$

So Foe $\max$ or $\min,$ Put $f'(x)=0\Rightarrow x=\pm 1$

So at $x=-1,$ We get $f''(-1) = -6,$ means $x=-1$ is a point of $\max$ and at $x=1,$

We get $f''(1)=6$ is a point of $\min$

Now drawing a rough graph, We get   roots of $f(x)$ as

one root lie in $(-2,-1)$ and other root in  $(0,1)$ and third root in$(1,2)$

Now how can i solve after that, Help required, Thanks

Comment: Are you sure of your integrals ? It is not $\int \frac{x^2-x}{(x^3-3x+1)^2}dx$ ? (ie no square for the factor $x^2-x$ in the $3$ integrals ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I appologize for my English. I hope that my explanation will be understandable for you.

For brevity, we will write the given sum in the following way:

$$
\left(\int_{-5}^{-2}+\int_{\frac{1}{6}}^{\frac{1}{3}}+\int_{\frac{6}{5}}^{\frac{3}{2}}\right)\left(\frac{x^2-x}{x^3-3x+1}\right)^2\,\mathrm dx
$$

First we find the corresponding indefinite integral

$$
\int \left(\frac{x^2-x}{x^3-3x+1}\right)^2\,\mathrm dx
$$

Using Ostrogradsky's integration method we express the integral as the sum

$$
\int \left(\frac{x^2-x}{x^3-3x+1}\right)^2\,\mathrm dx=\frac{Ax^2+Bx+C}{x^3-3x+1}+\int \frac{Dx^2+Ex+F}{x^3-3x+1}\,\mathrm dx
$$

that we differentiate:

\begin{align}
\left(\frac{x^2-x}{x^3-3x+1}\right)^2&=\left(\frac{Ax^2+Bx+C}{x^3-3x+1}\right)'+\frac{Dx^2+Ex+F}{x^3-3x+1}\\[6pt]
\left(\frac{x^2-x}{x^3-3x+1}\right)^2&=\frac{(2Ax+B)(x^3-3x+1)-(Ax^2+Bx+C)(3x^2-3)}{(x^3-3x+1)^2}+\frac{Dx^2+Ex+F}{x^3-3x+1}
\end{align}

Now we compare the coefficients in the numerators at both sides of the identity and we obtain

$$
A=-\frac 59\,,\quad B=\frac 89\,,\quad C=-\frac 29\,,\quad D=0,\quad E=\frac 49\,,\quad F=-\frac 29
$$

Thus

\begin{align}
\int\left(\frac{x^2-x}{x^3-3x+1}\right)^2\,\mathrm dx
&=-\frac 19\cdot\frac{5x^2-8x+2}{x^3-3x+1}
+\frac 29\int\frac{2x-1}{x^3-3x+1}\,\mathrm dx\\[6pt]
\left(\int_{-5}^{-2}+\int_{\frac{1}{6}}^{\frac{1}{3}}+\int_{\frac{6}{5}}^{\frac{3}{2}}\right)\left(\frac{x^2-x}{x^3-3x+1}\right)^2\,\mathrm dx
&=\left.-\frac 19\cdot\frac{5x^2-8x+2}{x^3-3x+1}\right|_{-5}^{-2}\left.-\frac 19\cdot\frac{5x^2-8x+2}{x^3-3x+1}\right|_{\frac 16}^{\frac 13}\\[6pt]
&\quad\left.-\frac 19\cdot\frac{5x^2-8x+2}{x^3-3x+1}\right|_{\frac 65}^{\frac 32}\\[6pt]
&\quad+\frac 29\left(\int_{-5}^{-2}+\int_{\frac{1}{6}}^{\frac{1}{3}}+\int_{\frac{6}{5}}^{\frac{3}{2}}\right)\frac{2x-1}{x^3-3x+1}\,\mathrm dx\\[6pt]
&=\frac{624}{109}+\frac 29\left(\int_{-5}^{-2}+\int_{\frac{1}{6}}^{\frac{1}{3}}+\int_{\frac{6}{5}}^{\frac{3}{2}}\right)\frac{2x-1}{x^3-3x+1}\,\mathrm dx
\end{align}

Now let us find the integral

$$
I:=\int\frac{2x-1}{x^3-3x+1}\,\mathrm dx
$$

If $a,b,c$ are mutually distinct real numbers then the general rational function

$$
f(x)=\frac{2x-1}{(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)}
$$

can be decomposed into three partial fractions that are easy to integrate

$$
\int\frac{2x-1}{(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)}\,\mathrm dx=\frac{2a-1}{(a-b)(a-c)}\log|x-a|+\frac{2b-1}{(b-a)(b-c)}\log|x-b|+\frac{2c-1}{(c-a)(c-b)}\log|x-c|
$$

It is not hard to show that

$$
\boldsymbol{x^3-3x+1=\left(x-2\cos\frac{2\pi}9\right)\left(x-2\cos\frac{4\pi}9\right)\left(x-2\cos\frac{8\pi}9\right)}
$$

Now we can calculate the integral $I$, i.e.

\begin{align}
I=\int\frac{2x-1}{x^3-3x+1}\,\mathrm dx
&=\underbrace{\frac{4\cos\frac{2\pi}9-1}{4(\cos\frac{2\pi}9-\cos\frac{4\pi}9)(\cos\frac{2\pi}9-\cos\frac{8\pi}9)}}_{\mathsf F_1}\log\left|x-2\cos\frac{2\pi}9\right|\\[6pt]
&\quad+\underbrace{\frac{4\cos\frac{4\pi}9-1}{4(\cos\frac{4\pi}9-\cos\frac{2\pi}9)(\cos\frac{4\pi}9-\cos\frac{8\pi}9)}}_{\mathsf F_2}\log\left|x-\cos\frac{4\pi}9\right|\\[6pt]
&\quad+\underbrace{\frac{4\cos\frac{8\pi}9-1}{4(\cos\frac{8\pi}9-\cos\frac{2\pi}9)(\cos\frac{8\pi}9-\cos\frac{4\pi}9)}}_{\mathsf F_3}\log\left|x-\cos\frac{8\pi}9\right|
\end{align}

It looks very complicated, however the fractions $\mathsf F_1$, $\mathsf F_2$, $\mathsf F_3$ can be reduced substantially. We just apply the identities

\begin{align}
\cos\alpha-\cos\beta&=-2\sin\frac{\alpha+\beta}2\sin\frac{\alpha-\beta}2\qquad(\spadesuit)\\
\cos2\alpha&=2\cos^2\alpha-1\qquad(\heartsuit)\\
\cos3\alpha&=4\cos^3\alpha-3\cos\alpha\qquad(\clubsuit)\qquad\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb R.
\end{align}

So we have

\begin{align}
\mathsf F_1
&=\frac{4\cos\frac{2\pi}9-1}{4(\cos\frac{2\pi}9-\cos\frac{4\pi}9)(\cos\frac{2\pi}9-\cos\frac{8\pi}9)}
=\frac{4\cos\frac{2\pi}9-1}{16\sin\frac{\pi}3\sin\frac{\pi}9\sin\frac{\pi}3\sin\frac{5\pi}9}
=\frac{4\cos\frac{2\pi}9-1}{12\sin\frac{\pi}9\sin\frac{5\pi}9}\\[6pt]
&=\frac{4\cos\frac{2\pi}9-1}{-6(\cos\frac{2\pi}3-\cos\frac{4\pi}9)}
=\frac 13\cdot\frac{4\cos\frac{2\pi}9-1}{1+2(2\cos^2\frac{2\pi}9-1)}
=\frac 13\cdot\frac{4\cos\frac{2\pi}9-1}{4\cos^2\frac{2\pi}9-1}\\[6pt]
&=\frac 13\cdot\frac{\cos\frac{2\pi}9(4\cos\frac{2\pi}9-1)}{4\cos^3\frac{2\pi}9-\cos\frac{2\pi}9}
=\frac 13\cdot\frac{\cos\frac{2\pi}9(4\cos\frac{2\pi}9-1)}{\cos\frac{2\pi}3+3\cos\frac{2\pi}9-\cos\frac{2\pi}9}
=\frac 13\cdot\frac{\cos\frac{2\pi}9(4\cos\frac{2\pi}9-1)}{-\frac 12+2\cos\frac{2\pi}9}\\[6pt]
&=\frac 23\cdot\frac{\cos\frac{2\pi}9(4\cos\frac{2\pi}9-1)}{4\cos\frac{2\pi}9-1}
=\boldsymbol{\frac 23\cos\frac{2\pi}9}\\[12pt]
\mathsf F_2
&=\frac{4\cos\frac{4\pi}9-1}{4(\cos\frac{4\pi}9-\cos\frac{2\pi}9)(\cos\frac{4\pi}9-\cos\frac{8\pi}9)}
=\frac{4\cos\frac{4\pi}9-1}{-16\sin\frac{\pi}3\sin\frac{\pi}9\sin\frac{2\pi}3\sin\frac{2\pi}9}
=\frac{4\cos\frac{4\pi}9-1}{-12\sin\frac{8\pi}9\sin\frac{2\pi}9}\\[6pt]
&=\frac{4\cos\frac{4\pi}9-1}{6(\cos\frac{10\pi}9-\cos\frac{2\pi}3)}
=\frac{4\cos\frac{4\pi}9-1}{6(\cos\frac{8\pi}9+\frac 12)}
=\frac 13\cdot\frac{4\cos\frac{4\pi}9-1}{2(2\cos^2\frac{4\pi}9-1)+1}
=\frac 13\cdot\frac{4\cos\frac{4\pi}9-1}{4\cos^2\frac{4\pi}9-1}\\[6pt]
&=\frac 13\cdot\frac{\cos\frac{4\pi}9(4\cos\frac{4\pi}9-1)}{4\cos^3\frac{4\pi}9-\cos\frac{4\pi}9}
=\frac 13\cdot\frac{\cos\frac{4\pi}9(4\cos\frac{4\pi}9-1)}{\cos\frac{4\pi}3+3\cos\frac{4\pi}9-\cos\frac{4\pi}9}
=\frac 13\cdot\frac{\cos\frac{4\pi}9(4\cos\frac{4\pi}9-1)}{-\frac 12+2\cos\frac{4\pi}9}\\[6pt]
&=\frac 23\cdot\frac{\cos\frac{4\pi}9(4\cos\frac{4\pi}9-1)}{4\cos\frac{4\pi}9-1}
=\boldsymbol{\frac 23\cos\frac{4\pi}9}\\[12pt]
\mathsf F_3
&=\frac{4\cos\frac{8\pi}9-1}{4(\cos\frac{8\pi}9-\cos\frac{2\pi}9)(\cos\frac{8\pi}9-\cos\frac{4\pi}9)}
=\frac{4\cos\frac{8\pi}9-1}{16\sin\frac{\pi}3\sin\frac{5\pi}9\sin\frac{\pi}3\sin\frac{2\pi}9}
=\frac{4\cos\frac{8\pi}9-1}{12\sin\frac{5\pi}9\sin\frac{2\pi}9}\\[6pt]
&=\frac{4\cos\frac{8\pi}9-1}{-6(\cos\frac{7\pi}9-\cos\frac{\pi}3)}
=\frac{4\cos\frac{8\pi}9-1}{6(\cos\frac{16\pi}9+\frac 12)}
=\frac 13\cdot\frac{4\cos\frac{8\pi}9-1}{2(2\cos^2\frac{8\pi}9-1)+1}
=\frac 13\cdot\frac{4\cos\frac{8\pi}9-1}{4\cos^2\frac{8\pi}9-1}\\[6pt]
&=\frac 13\cdot\frac{\cos\frac{8\pi}9(4\cos\frac{8\pi}9-1)}{4\cos^3\frac{8\pi}9-\cos\frac{8\pi}9}
=\frac 13\cdot\frac{\cos\frac{8\pi}9(4\cos\frac{8\pi}9-1)}{\cos\frac{8\pi}3+3\cos\frac{8\pi}9-\cos\frac{8\pi}9}
=\frac 13\cdot\frac{\cos\frac{8\pi}9(4\cos\frac{8\pi}9-1)}{-\frac 12+2\cos\frac{8\pi}9}\\[6pt]
&=\frac 23\cdot\frac{\cos\frac{8\pi}9(4\cos\frac{8\pi}9-1)}{4\cos\frac{8\pi}9-1}
=\boldsymbol{\frac 23\cos\frac{8\pi}9}
\end{align}

We replace the fractions $\mathsf F_1$, $\mathsf F_2$, $\mathsf F_3$ by simple trigonometric expressions in the integral $I$ and we get

$$
\int\frac{2x-1}{x^3-3x+1}\,\mathrm dx
=\frac 23\left(\cos\frac{2\pi}9\log\left|x-2\cos\frac{2\pi}9\right|
+\cos\frac{4\pi}9\log\left|x-\cos\frac{4\pi}9\right|
+\cos\frac{8\pi}9\log\left|x-\cos\frac{8\pi}9\right|\right)
$$

Now we use the derived primitive function to find the sum of definite integrals and we deduce that

\begin{align}
\left(\int_{-5}^{-2}+\int_{\frac{1}{6}}^{\frac{1}{3}}+\int_{\frac{6}{5}}^{\frac{3}{2}}\right)&\frac{2x-1}{x^3-3x+1}\,\mathrm dx\\[6pt]
&=\left.\frac 23\left(\cos\frac{2\pi}9\log\left|x-2\cos\frac{2\pi}9\right|
+\cos\frac{4\pi}9\log\left|x-\cos\frac{4\pi}9\right|
+\cos\frac{8\pi}9\log\left|x-\cos\frac{8\pi}9\right|\right)\right|_{-5}^{-2}\\[6pt]
&\quad+\left.\frac 23\left(\cos\frac{2\pi}9\log\left|x-2\cos\frac{2\pi}9\right|
+\cos\frac{4\pi}9\log\left|x-\cos\frac{4\pi}9\right|
+\cos\frac{8\pi}9\log\left|x-\cos\frac{8\pi}9\right|\right)\right|_{\frac 16}^{\frac 13}\\[6pt]
&\quad+\left.\frac 23\left(\cos\frac{2\pi}9\log\left|x-2\cos\frac{2\pi}9\right|
+\cos\frac{4\pi}9\log\left|x-\cos\frac{4\pi}9\right|
+\cos\frac{8\pi}9\log\left|x-\cos\frac{8\pi}9\right|\right)\right|_{\frac 65}^{\frac 32}\\[6pt]
&=\frac 23\cos\frac{2\pi}9\log\Biggl|\underbrace{\frac{(-2-2\cos\frac{2\pi}9)(\frac 13-2\cos\frac{2\pi}9)(\frac 32-2\cos\frac{2\pi}9)}{(-5-2\cos\frac{2\pi}9)(\frac 16-2\cos\frac{2\pi}9)(\frac 65-2\cos\frac{2\pi}9)}}_{\mathsf F_4}\Biggr|\\[6pt]
&\quad+\frac 23\cos\frac{4\pi}9\log\Biggl|\underbrace{\frac{(-2-2\cos\frac{4\pi}9)(\frac 13-2\cos\frac{4\pi}9)(\frac 32-2\cos\frac{4\pi}9)}{(-5-2\cos\frac{4\pi}9)(\frac 16-2\cos\frac{4\pi}9)(\frac 65-2\cos\frac{4\pi}9)}}_{\mathsf F_5}\Biggr|\\[6pt]
&\quad+\frac 23\cos\frac{8\pi}9\log\Biggl|\underbrace{\frac{(-2-2\cos\frac{8\pi}9)(\frac 13-2\cos\frac{8\pi}9)(\frac 32-2\cos\frac{8\pi}9)}{(-5-2\cos\frac{8\pi}9)(\frac 16-2\cos\frac{8\pi}9)(\frac 65-2\cos\frac{8\pi}9)}}_{\mathsf F_6}\Biggr|
\end{align}

The fractions $\mathsf F_4$, $\mathsf F_5$, $\mathsf F_6$ can be simplified using the trigonometric identities  $\heartsuit$, $\clubsuit$. We rearrange $\mathsf F_4$ only. We obtain the same results after rearranging the fractions $\mathsf F_5$, $\mathsf F_6$.

\begin{align}
\mathsf F_4
&=\frac{(-2-2\cos\frac{2\pi}9)(\frac 13-2\cos\frac{2\pi}9)(\frac 32-2\cos\frac{2\pi}9)}{(-5-2\cos\frac{2\pi}9)(\frac 16-2\cos\frac{2\pi}9)(\frac 65-2\cos\frac{2\pi}9)}\\[6pt]
&=5\cdot\frac{24\cos^3\frac{2\pi}9+2\cos^2\frac{2\pi}9-19\cos\frac{2\pi}9+3}{120\cos^3\frac{2\pi}9+218\cos^2\frac{2\pi}9-199\cos\frac{2\pi}9+15}\\[6pt]
&=5\cdot\frac{6(\cos\frac{2\pi}3+3\cos\frac{2\pi}9)+\cos\frac{4\pi}9+1-19\cos\frac{2\pi}9+3}{30(\cos\frac{2\pi}3+3\cos\frac{2\pi}9)+109(\cos\frac{4\pi}9+1)-199\cos\frac{2\pi}9+15}\\[6pt]
&=5\cdot\frac{1-\cos\frac{2\pi}9+\cos\frac{4\pi}9}{109-109\cos\frac{2\pi}9+109\cos\frac{4\pi}9}
=\frac 5{109}\cdot\frac{1-\cos\frac{2\pi}9+\cos\frac{4\pi}9}{1-\cos\frac{2\pi}9+\cos\frac{4\pi}9}
=\boldsymbol{\frac 5{109}}\\[12pt]
\mathsf F_5
&=\frac{(-2-2\cos\frac{4\pi}9)(\frac 13-2\cos\frac{4\pi}9)(\frac 32-2\cos\frac{4\pi}9)}{(-5-2\cos\frac{4\pi}9)(\frac 16-2\cos\frac{4\pi}9)(\frac 65-2\cos\frac{4\pi}9)}=\dots=\boldsymbol{\frac 5{109}}\\[12pt]
\mathsf F_6
&=\frac{(-2-2\cos\frac{8\pi}9)(\frac 13-2\cos\frac{8\pi}9)(\frac 32-2\cos\frac{8\pi}9)}{(-5-2\cos\frac{8\pi}9)(\frac 16-2\cos\frac{8\pi}9)(\frac 65-2\cos\frac{8\pi}9)}=\dots=\boldsymbol{\frac 5{109}}\\[12pt]
\end{align}

Now we return to the sum of three definite integrals and calculate it using the trigonometric identity

$$
\cos\alpha+\cos\beta=2\cos\frac{\alpha+\beta}2\cos\frac{\alpha-\beta}2\qquad\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb R.
$$

So we have

\begin{align}
\boldsymbol{\left(\int_{-5}^{-2}+\int_{\frac{1}{6}}^{\frac{1}{3}}+\int_{\frac{6}{5}}^{\frac{3}{2}}\right)\frac{2x-1}{x^3-3x+1}\,\mathrm dx}
&=\frac 23\cos\frac{2\pi}9\log\frac 5{109}+\frac 23\cos\frac{4\pi}9\log\frac 5{109}+\frac 23\cos\frac{8\pi}9\log\frac 5{109}\\[6pt]
&=\frac 23\log\frac 5{109}\left(\cos\frac{2\pi}9+\cos\frac{4\pi}9+\cos\frac{8\pi}9\right)\\[6pt]
&=\frac 23\log\frac 5{109}\left(2\cos\frac{\pi}3\cos\frac{\pi}9-\cos\frac{\pi}9\right)\\[6pt]
&=\frac 23\log\frac 5{109}\left(\cos\frac{\pi}9-\cos\frac{\pi}9\right)=\boldsymbol 0
\end{align}

Finally

\begin{align}
\left(\int_{-5}^{-2}+\int_{\frac{1}{6}}^{\frac{1}{3}}+\int_{\frac{6}{5}}^{\frac{3}{2}}\right)\left(\frac{x^2-x}{x^3-3x+1}\right)^2\,\mathrm dx
&=\frac{624}{109}+\frac 29\left(\int_{-5}^{-2}+\int_{\frac{1}{6}}^{\frac{1}{3}}+\int_{\frac{6}{5}}^{\frac{3}{2}}\right)\frac{2x-1}{x^3-3x+1}\,\mathrm dx\\[12pt]
\large\color{blue}{\left(\int_{-5}^{-2}+\int_{\frac{1}{6}}^{\frac{1}{3}}+\int_{\frac{6}{5}}^{\frac{3}{2}}\right)\left(\frac{x^2-x}{x^3-3x+1}\right)^2\,\mathrm dx}&\,\color{blue}{\large=\frac{624}{109}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

The point is to find that the integrand function is continuous at every of these three segments. In other words, you need to proof that the roots of $ f(x) = x^3 - 3x + 1 $ are not in any of the segments at witch you want to integrate. You can do these by analysing the monoton behaviour of these function. For example, $f(-2) < 0$ and you know that the function is monotonically increasing from $-5$ to $-2$, so you are sure about the first integral.

From $-1 $ to $ 1 $ the function is monotonically decreasing. So, if $ f\big(\frac{1} {6}\big) > 0 $ and  $ f\big(\frac{1} {3}\big) > 0 $ (you have to show that), there is no zero of these function at the segment $\big[\frac{1}{6}, \frac{1}{3} \big]$.

The same with the third - use the values at the end points and the monotonic behaviour of the function at that segment. (monotonically increasing, $f\big[\frac{6}{5} \big] < 0$, and $f\big[\frac{3}{2} \big] < 0$)

The rest you probably have to do using numerical integration. The usual way with partial fraction decomposition doesn't help. The indefinite integral can't be solved using elementary functions.